# ActiveRecord does insane numbers of SHOW FIELDS

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

According to innotop and Cacti, my database server is handling about 8 times as many `SHOW FIELDS` statements than `SELECT` or any other productive query. I'm using Rails 3.0, so it should cache the columns once they're loaded. I've seen reports that MySQL requires a temp table for every `SHOW FIELDS` query, and my monitoring data bears that out too.

Admittedly, I am using ActiveRecord/Rails in a non-standard situation that involves starting lots (~400) of processes across a 100-200 computers that each load the entire Rails environment. These processes run for at least a few minutes, potentially 24+ hours, doing short bursts of database work every few minutes. Note that these processes don't use the normal HTTP request/response loop.

Is there any way to avoid this? We do have `config.cache_classes = true` in our `config/environments/production.rb` file. I'm actually running into database server scaling problems, and I think this issue is a major factor.

Comment: "Admittedly, I am using ActiveRecord/Rails in a non-standard situation that involves starting lots (~400) of processes across a 100-200 computers that each load the entire Rails environment." Err.. wtf? That's a little nuts. Why don't you just fork the processes on each machine after the environment is loaded?

Comment: I probably wasn't clear @JohnFeminella - I've got 1 or 2 Ruby processes on each machine that load the application environment, not 100+ per machine. These processes are launched through a cluster load balancer so they co-exist well with more interactive jobs launched by users.